# Databinding setting to null and starting new

Tags: wpf, data-binding, null, new-operator, datacontext

I have in my App class an object Order, both implementing INotfiyPropertyChanged.
When an Order is concluded, I set it to null and do a new Order() for restarting a new Order.

The problem is: it seems the objects that whose DataContext was bound to Order seems they are always linked to the older Order

What can I do to for not having to rebind again manually when I restart an Order? 
For every object with this DataContext, I need to do object.DataContext= App.Order. What can I do to avoid this?

Some code:

```
public partial class App : Application, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Order m_order = new Order();

    public Order Order
    {
        get { return m_order; }
        set
        {
            m_order = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Order");
        }
    }
    //...

    public bool getOrderClosed()
    {
        if (Order != null)
        {
             Order = null;
        }

        return (Order == null);
    }

    public bool getOrderOpened()
    {
        if (Order == null)
            Order = new Order();

        return (Order != null);
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

 //code on the part where the order is finished

    private void Confirm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //...
        if (SaveOrder())
        {
            theApp.getOrderClosed();
            theApp.getOrderOpened();
            theApp.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.Basket.DataContext = theApp.Order;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Show us your exact code. Containing the property implementations, the setting to null and the bindings that do not appear to update.

Comment: This line is now solving the problem.
 theApp.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.Basket.DataContext = theApp.Order;

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your Order object *is* the DataContext. If you're setting the DataContext in codebehind, it'd looks something like:

```
[some_element].DataContext = myApp.Order;
```

What you'd need to do is **bind** the DataContext to myApp.Order. This way, when you do something like

```
myApp.Order = new Order(...);
```

the DataContext for [some_element] will change as well. If you post your XAML code where you're using the Order object as the DataContext, I can show you exactly what your binding on the DataContext should look like.

With what you've done, only the changes *within* the DataContext will be picked up; when you change the *property* that you're using as the DataContext changes, the DataContext itself does not.

Comment: for example:

in code I do something in UserControl like:


theUserControl.DataContext = theApp.Order; 


UserControl encapsulates the field:

<TextBox x:Name="FirstPhone"  Text="{Binding FirstPhone,Mode=TwoWay}" .../>

where FirstPhone is a Property of Order that Notifies its own changes

Comment: And do you set the databinding to null and then to your newer object every time you create a new Order?

Comment: Kshitij Mehta:  Setting the binding, is that the binding of the FirstPhone UI element and some like this one? No, I don't set any. Isn't it the idea of the XAML Binding concept that you don't have to touch the Binding and the Data themselves notify about their changes to the associated Bindings?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a few weeks ago. I found that when assigning a bound property to a new object the binding was lost, so as a workaround I had to create a new temp object and then copy all the fields into my bound property, that way you effectivly have a fresh object and the binding is maintained.

Hope this helps!

Comment: May be I will have to implement a Init() function, that reinitializes everything in the Order Class. And instead, of initializing everything in the class members' declarations, I could reuse this function inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change the binding to `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`?

Comment: That only affects the direction target->source which is not the problem here.

Comment: It seems to me: the problem here is not the CHANGE internal to the object, but the CREATION of a new object,that is in another location in memory, and the DataContext property of bound objects is not able to adapt to this occurence.

Answer (score 0):

If App implements INotifyPropertyChanged properly, it will fire when you set App.Order to a new instance, and the binding will update.

Are you sure it is implemented properly?
eg.

```
class App
{
    public Order Order
    {
        get 
        {
            return _order;
        }
        set
        { 
            if (value != _order)
            {
                 _order = value;
                 FirePropertyChanged("Order");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that suppost to be a proper implementation or an example of an improper one? I hope it is the latter.

Comment: As you can see in my code, that is similar to yours - the only difference is the condition if (value != _order) - this will solve nothing. If it with mine, obviously, it will not work with yours.

Comment: And how are your objects that are not updating bound? Are they "App.Order.SomeProperty", or some other method. We need to see the XAML

Comment: If I do watch of the DataContext, I see the data of the old order, so, that is irrelevant.